# Correct way to schedule a task

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm coding a cache server in Ruby and I need to make expiration times for the data I'm storing. So when the user stores data under the key `foo` for example he also sets an expiration time in seconds. The data needs to be deleted at that moment so what I thought for this scheduling is to create a thread and put it to sleep until that time comes.

```
Thread.new(@options[:exp_time], key) do |t, k|
    exp = Time.now + t
    sleep(t)
    if @data.key?(k) && @data[k][:exp_time] <= exp #check if it hasn't been updated
        @data.delete(k)
    end
end
```

t is the time that the user sent and key is the key under which the data is stored. The expiration time could also be changed if a user replaces the data stored at the key so I check it. I was wondering if this a good use of threads or if it consumes too much resources or there's an easier way. I can't use gems or libraries of any type. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's going to create a crazy number of threads in a very short time if this is put under load. What you really want is a priority queue where the elements are sorted by expiration time and a periodic timer that checks if the first entry is expired, processes it, and repeats that until there's nothing left to expire, then goes back to sleep briefly.

There's a few Ruby gems that implement this sort of thing, any one that performs adequately will do, or you could write your own, it's not too hard, using [`bsearch_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index) to quickly find the insertion point.

I think you'll find a single queue with one thread will work much better than potentially thousands of threads. Each thread carries a fairly significant amount of overhead so it's best to keep these to a minimum.

Comment: thanks once again, yeah it kind of looked wrong but It was the only way of deleting the keys at the exact time. But what are a few seconds more compared to not having a hundred threads running

Comment: It's highly unlikely to be lagging behind more than a handful of milliseconds if you do this right.